# Rails, Devise & Omniauth - problems with setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I am trying (again) to set up authentications with Rails 4, devise and omniauth.

I tried to follow the example in this post: [Rails 4, Devise, Omniauth (with multiple providers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249749/rails-4-devise-omniauth-with-multiple-providers)

I have these gems installed:

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-linkedin-oauth2'
gem 'oauth2'
```

I have a user model, and an authentications model.

I have:

User.rb:

```
  has_many :authentications

def disapprove
    self.approved = false
  end

  def approve
    self.approved = true
  end
```

SOCIALS = {
      facebook: 'Facebook',
      google_oauth2: 'Google',
      linkedin: 'Linkedin'
    }

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth, current_user)
  authentication = Authentication.where(:provider => auth.provider,
                                  :uid => auth.uid.to_s, 
                                  :token => auth.credentials.token, 
                                  :secret => auth.credentials.secret).first_or_initialize
  authentication.profile_page = auth.info.urls.first.last unless authentication.persisted?
  if authentication.user.blank?
    user = current_user.nil? ? User.where('email = ?', auth['info']['email']).first : current_user
    if user.blank?
      user = User.new
      user.skip_confirmation!
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
      user.fetch_details(auth)
      user.save
    end
    authentication.user = user
    authentication.save
  end
  authentication.user 
end  

def fetch_details(auth)
  self.first_name = auth.info.first_name
  self.last_name = auth.info.last_name
  self.email = auth.info.email
  self.image = URI.parse(auth.info.image)
end
```

Authentication.rb

```
 belongs_to :user
```

Routes.rb

```
devise_for :users,
             :controllers => {
:registrations => "users/registrations",


             :omniauth_callbacks => 'users/omniauth_callbacks',
           }
```

User/registrations_controller

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController 
  #before_filter :check_permissions , :only => [ :new, :create, :cancel ] 
  #skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication 

  def check_permissions
    authorize! :create, resource
  end

  def index
    if params[:approved] == "false"
      @users = User.find_all_by_approved(false)
    else
      @users = User.all
    end
  end

    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params) #(params[:user])

        respond_to do |format|
          if resource.save
            # Tell the UserMailer to send a welcome email after save
            # {@user.send_admin_mail
            # @user.send_user_welcome_mail}

            format.html { redirect_to(profile_path(@user.profile))}
            #, notice: 'We have received your registration. We will be in touch shortly.') }
            #format.json { render json: root_path, status: :created, location: @user }
          else
            #format.html { redirect_to(root_path, alert: 'Sorry! There was a problem with your registration. Please contact us to sort it out.') }
            format.html { render action: 'new' }
            format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      private
      def user_params
          params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password )
        end



      # protected
      #   def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      #     'subscribers/new'
      #   end
end
```

User/Omniauth_callbacks controller

class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

```
    # try again following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249749/rails-4-devise-omniauth-with-multiple-providers

  def all
    user = User.from_omniauth(env['omniauth.auth'], current_user)
    if user.persisted?
      sign_in user
      flash[:notice] = t('devise.omniauth_callbacks.success', :kind => User::SOCIALS[params[:action].to_sym])
      if user.sign_in_count == 1
        redirect_to profile_path(@user.profile)
      else
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    else
      session['devise.user_attributes'] = user.attributes
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  User::SOCIALS.each do |k, _|
    alias_method k, :all
  end
end
```

The devise/new registrations view says:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">

                  <%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
                          <div class="facebookauth">
                            <%= link_to "Join with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %>
                          </div>
                  <% end -%>

                </div>
              </div>


          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

              <%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
                  <div class="googleauth">
                    <%= link_to "Join with Google", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2) %>
                  </div>
              <% end -%>
            </div>
          </div>



      <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">

                  <%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
                      <div class="linkedinauth">
                        <%= link_to "Join with LinkedIn", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:linkedin) %>
                      </div>
                  <% end -%>
              </div>
      </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

              <%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
                  <div class="twitterauth">
                    <%= link_to "Join with Twitter", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:twitter) %>
                  </div>
              <% end -%>

            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="emailform">
            <div class="form-inputs", style="margin-left: 7%">


                  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
                  <%= f.input :first_name,  :label_html => {:class => 'deviselabels'}, autofocus: true, required: false, :input_html => {:maxlength => 15, :size => 40, class: 'lineitemdevise'} %>
                  <%= f.input :last_name, :label_html => {:class => 'deviselabels'}, required: false, :input_html => {:maxlength => 15, :size => 40, class: 'lineitemdevise'} %>
                  <%= f.input :email, :label_html => {:class => 'deviselabels'}, required: false, autofocus: false, placeholder: "Please use your work or university address", :input_html => {:maxlength => 55, :size => 40, class: 'lineitemdevise'} %>
                  <%= f.input :password, :label_html => {:class => 'deviselabels'}, required: false, placeholder: "Minimum 8 characters", :input_html => {:maxlength => 15, :size => 40, class: 'lineitemdevise'} %>
                </div>

            <div class="form-actions">
          <%= f.button :submit, "Join by email", :class => "dcpb" %>
         </div>
          <% end %>
          </div>
      </div>
```

I have another model called profile.rb.

```
profile belongs_to user
```

Problems:

1. None of this works. When I click on each of the social media login links, the page just jumps to the sign up by email form.

The heroku logs error message says:

```
(facebook) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, : 
2015-11-03T07:05:48.237549+00:00 app[web.1]: {"error":{"message":"Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"HD3mnzmSTEw"}}
```

2. When I complete the sign up by email form with an email and password, the user name is recognised (in that the navbar says Hello , but when I go into the rails console, the user is not listed.

Also, when I click on the user name, I get an error which says that profile does not exist. The heroku logs say:

```
(Couldn't find Profile with 'id'=3)
```

3. Is there another step required to make the social media registrations work to create a new user?

MY NEXT ATTEMPT:

I've changed all of the above and tried again, following the approach in the Railscasts videos.

I now use a user model and an authentications model.

In the user.rb, I have:

```
  has_many :authentications, :dependent => :delete_all

def apply_omniauth(omniauth)
      authentications.build(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'], :token => auth['credentials']['token'])

end
```

authentication.rb

```
belongs_to :user

def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do | user |
        authentication.provider = auth.provider
        authentication.uid = auth.uid
        authentication.user.first_name = auth.first_name
        authentication.user.last_name = auth.last_name
        authentication.user.image = auth.info.image

    end
  end
```

Authentications_controller:

```
class AuthenticationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_authentication, only: [:destroy]

  def index
    @authentications = current_user.authentications if current_user
  end


  def create
    omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])
    if authentication
      sign_in_and_redirect_user(:user, authentication.user.profile)

    elsif current_user
      current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])
      redirect_to user.profile_url
    else
      user = User.new
      user.omniauth(omniauth)
      if user.save!
        sign_in_and_redirect_user(:user, user.profile)
      else
        session[:omniauth] = omniauth.except('extra')
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
      end
    end  
  end

  def destroy
    @authentication.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to authentications_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_authentication
      @authentication = current_user.authentications.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

In the routes.rb, I have:

```
 devise_for :users,
             :controllers => {
                :registrations => "users/registrations",
           }
 patch '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'authentications#create'
```

Omniauth.rb

require 'omniauth-facebook'
require 'omniauth-google-oauth2'

OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

```
 Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
   provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'],
     :scope => 'public_profile', info_fields: 'id,first_name,last_name,link,email',
     :display => 'popup',
     :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => '/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'}}
```

Then when I try this, I get this error:

```
(facebook) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, : 
2015-11-05T06:4839+00:00 app[web.1]: {"error":{"message":"Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"CrvXN22Z"}}
```

I find the next part of the error message odd because it refers to the callbacks controller which I no longer use (the whole thing is commented out and there is no route for it).

```
Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, : 
2015-11-05T08:24:16.010951+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
2015-11-05T08:24:16.012648+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://www.dder.com/users/sign_in
```

A FURTHER ATTEMPT

I have been trying to set up devise with omniauth for more than 1.5 years now. This is my latest attempt (following the Sitepoint tutorial at sitepoint.com/rails-authentication-oauth-2-0-omniauth). I've tried to use this tutorial before and not had any success, so I've made some tweaks to try and adapt it to some aspects of other tutorials on this topic.

I now have:

user.rb

```
  has_many :authentications, :dependent => :delete_all

def apply_omniauth(omniauth)
      authentications.build(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'], :token => auth['credentials']['token'])

  end
```

authentication.rb

```
belongs_to :user
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do | user |
        authentication.provider = auth.provider
        authentication.uid = auth.uid
        authentication.user.first_name = auth.first_name
        authentication.user.last_name = auth.last_name
        authentication.user.image = auth.info.image

    end
  end
```

authentications controller

```
    class AuthenticationsController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
      before_action :set_authentication, only: [:destroy]

      def index
        @authentications = current_user.authentications if current_user
      end


      def create
        omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
        authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])
        if authentication
          sign_in_and_redirect_user(:user, authentication.user.profile)

        elsif current_user
          current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])
          redirect_to user.profile_url
        else
          user = User.new
          user.omniauth(omniauth)
          if user.save!
            sign_in_and_redirect_user(:user, user.profile)
          else
            session[:omniauth] = omniauth.except('extra')
            redirect_to new_user_registration_url
          end
        end  
      end

      def destroy
        @authentication.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to authentications_url }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_authentication
          @authentication = current_user.authentications.find(params[:id])
        end
    end
```

registrations controller

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController 
  #before_filter :check_permissions , :only => [ :new, :create, :cancel ] 
  #skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication 
  # before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller? # Suggestion from Sitepoint tutorial - not currently implemented because not sure about the difference between this and set params.

  def check_permissions
    authorize! :create, resource
  end

  def index
    if params[:approved] == "false"
      @users = User.find_all_by_approved(false)
    else
      @users = User.all
    end
  end

  def create
    super
    session[:omniauth] = nil unless @user.new_record?
  end

  # THIS IS A SUGGESTION FROM SITEPOINT TUTORIAL 
  # protected

  #   def configure_permitted_parameters
  #     devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << [:first_name, :last_name]
  #   end


  private
    def user_params
          params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password )
    end

    def build_resource(*args)
        super
        if session[:omniauth]
        @user.apply_omniauth(session[:omniauth])
        @user.valid?
        end
    end  

end
```

routes

```
devise_for :users,
             :controllers => {
                :registrations => "users/registrations",
                :omniauth_callbacks => "authentications"
                # :omniauth_callbacks => 'users/omniauth_callbacks',
           }

get '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'authentications#create'
```

I can check these routes with:

```
rake routes | grep auth
                      user_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /users/auth/:provider(.:format)                                                                 authentications#passthru {:provider=>/facebook|linkedin|twitter|google_oauth2/}
                       user_omniauth_callback GET|POST /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format)                                                          authentications#:action
                                              GET      /auth/:provider/callback(.:format)                                                              authentications#create
```

new registration partial in the view

```
<%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
                  <div class="twitterauth">
                    <%= link_to "Join with Twitter", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:twitter) %>
                  </div>
              <% end -%>
```

I'm really not sure where this path is coming from. Not sure why it's named as it is.

new session partial in the view

```
 <%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
                  <div class="twitterauth">
                    <%= link_to "Login with Twitter", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:twitter) %>
                  </div>
              <% end -%>
```

Current error:

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound at /users/auth/twitter/callback

The action 'twitter' could not be found for AuthenticationsController
```

Comment: Have you set up the environment variables ENV['FACEBOOK_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'] on Heroku?

Comment: Yes - they are correctly configured in Heroku

Comment: Oauth 2.01 has a specific problem. You need to specify a callback url in the device oauth:    config. config.omniauth :facebook, "APP_ID", "APP_SECRET", callback_url: "CALLBACK_URL"    . If that doesn't work have you checked the credentials and app settings in facebook?Your domain need to be exactly same as in your local environment?

Comment: longest question ever seen on SO

Answer (score 1):

Devise comes with an out of the box solution for integration with omniuth. You can checkout these urls: 
1. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-devise-and-omniauth-for-your-rails-application
This one shows integration with DigitalOcean but can be extended to others.
2. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3A-Overview
This one is from devise wiki

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Udit. I've tried the digital ocean one already. Thanks anyway. I regularly consult the gem documentation. I have a string of problems with that.

Comment: Have you checked that your callback_url matches the one present on your facebook app configuration. From the heroku logs it seems your callback_url and facebook's callback_url dosent match. Try debugging the gems themselves to see what the callback_url method returns.

Comment: I encountered this callback_url does not match error when I was trying integration with instagram. There was an issue related to that. You can find the fix here: [https://github.com/ropiku/omniauth-instagram/issues/23] Maybe similar problem with facebook in your case

Answer (score 0):

There is a gem called [dom](https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/domp) that  was made exclusively to manage Devise with multiple providers. It makes things deadly simple!

Also, I think you should read these articles. I'm sure you can solve all your questions with them:

1. [Devise OmniAuth: Overview](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview)
2. [OmniAuth Managing multiple provaders](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Managing-Multiple-Providers)

Comment: Hi Alfonso, thanks for the suggestions. I consult the gem docs regularly. Having tried at least 200 times (you can see at least 40 other questions on this board relating to those articles), I found tutorials and tried to follow those. This question is related to a tutorials.